# Algorithm for condition checking over arbitrary time periods

Tags: algorithm, range, conditional-statements

*Some definitions:
Timeline: The range of time all of the below operates on. A start time and an end time.
Range- a subset of the timeline.
Context: A collection of key, value pairs.
Event: Occurs at a specific time on a timeline and modifies some subset of the values in the context.
Condition: Collection of conditions on the key, values in the context. Evaluates to true or false depending on the context's state.
Given the above:

I have a timeline with events at certain times that modify the context
I have a collection of arbitrary, generic conditions and I want to find the ranges of time that those conditions pass.
For example, My condition is foo = true and bar = true. Event at time 0 sets foo to true and bar to false. Event at time 5 sets bar to true. Event at time 6 sets foo to false. Event at time 8 sets foo to true. Timeline has no more events and has max time 10. The correct return value would be the range from 5 to 6 and the range from 8 to 10.

I'm basically doing the brute force thing right now, going from beginning to end, applying the events to the context, and at each event evaluating the context to see if it passes the condition, and if it does, continuing to move forward and test events until the context fails the condition, and at that point, storing the range.

The challenge is that it's seeming like these events are only going to become more numerous, and there are many of these groups of conditions, and it's becoming slow. Any ideas for strategies? I think it's possible I can infer whether or not a condition will care about an event or not (can I skip testing the condition on an event because it won't effect the condition?), but not sure if that will produce much speedup. Can I preprocess the event list at all to make this faster? This seems similar to a range overlap algorithm, but with its own challenges.

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in this question. That is, there is no concept of what language, what "context", "event", or "node" means. More details are instrumental to a good answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with Esper (http://www.espertech.com/esper/index.php)?

Comment: Edited post to clarify question.

Comment: How many events/properties are we talking about here?

Comment: The problem is that it's been more discrete events and now I'm seeing cases where the values are changing more continuously across the time scale, which I could represent with many discrete events. The conditions are on the order of 10 different ones or so, but they're tested a lot over each of the events.